# Can tile adhesive be used as grout for a single tile?

Tags: uk, tiling

We've added a room to the side of our house and an entranceway has been knocked through the kitchen wall into the room. A doorframe is going to be fitted in the entranceway on the side of the new room, but because the entrance is through an external wall, it is quite deep and we therefore need to extend our kitchen tiling by *a single tile* into the non-doorframe side of the entranceway. (We've laid a spare tile down [approximately 14cm by 83cm] and it fits extremely well, big enough to slide just under the plaster sides of the entrance and deep enough to span from the current kitchen floor to the doorframe where it will meet laminate from the new room.)

The guides we've read all say use an adhesive to stick the tile to the subfloor (newly poured screed) and then grout the space between tiles, but we are reluctant to buy large  sacks of adhesive and grout (can you get ~1kg sizes??) to install a single tile. In this instance, what problems would arise if we filled the (2mm) gap between the new tile and the existing floor with adhesive or (much less likely) tried to adhere to the subfloor with grout? Thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: You might be able to get/buy the small amount of the stuff you need from a builder/tiler/floor installer.  The stores might have small containers also, but the price is usually more than larger amounts.

Comment: @isherwood 'adhesive' appears to be the name used in the UK -- hopefully your change of the title doesn't negatively impact responses.

Comment: Adhesive is a generic term for all kinds of things. It's important to be specific. There are multiple types in the UK, too. :)

Comment: It's important to use words that people understand; I don't know what mastic is or what 'mortar' is in this context because products in the UK aren't labelled that way. I've updated the title to 'tile adhesive' and added 'for a single tile' since a small amount of research makes it clear you wouldn't want to use adhesive as grouting for a full installation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use mortar as grout. You can also use mastic, but it'll be more difficult to work with as it tends to be stickier. They would both support the tile edges to more or less the same degree once hardened.

If the tiles are very close together you could even probably get away with silicone caulk in a suitable color.

That said, the price of a small package of grout would be worth a decent final appearance to most people.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Grout fillers.

Sanded and not sanded.

The sanded is recommended for spacing bigger than 1/4 inch while the non sanded is for spaces below the 1/4 inch

Mortar is good for filling spaces between the bricks but not so good for tiles unless you have very large gaps to fill.

Comment: All of this is true. I don't see how any of it answers the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get tubs of ready-mixed all-in-one tile adhesive plus grout. Mapei and Evo-Stik both appear to sell such a product.